Maven plugin to build Docker images with a multi staged Dockerfile
How can I build a Docker image that is based on a multi-staged build process?
I know that Kaniko can perform the job. How can I use that from within a Maven file?
Q2: Paketo build are getting more popular. Is there a way to build with a Dockerfile? I know that Paketo tries to do the heavy lifting without any Dockerfile.
Let me give a simplistic (old) example: build a Spring Boot app consisting of both Angular frontend and a Java backend. Building maven allows running first 'npm' to build the frontend part and add it to the resources path. Then compile the Spring Boot app taking the frontend from the resources path.
Can you give a working example?

Q2: Cloud-Native Buildpacks do not use Dockerfiles. It's a simpler approach for 90% of the apps where things will just work with CNBs. When you come to buildpacks from Dockerfiles, it's common to think in Dockerfiles. Maybe I can help translate to buildpacks. What specifically are you trying to do? How would you typically do that with Dockerfiles?

As you said, in 90% of the cases the standard Paketo building suffices. But there are cases when multi-staged building is better.

Interesting question. Let me learn about Kaniko. I will update you if I come up with anything.

@tm1701 You're thinking in terms of Dockerfiles. Every buildpack build is effectively multi-staged because of the way CNBs are designed. The build stage is always separated from the runtime and CNBs will keep files out of runtime that don't need to be there. Classic example is your languages compiler tools. A CNB can install that for your, run it, but ensure it doesn't go into the resulting runtime app image. So you get all the benefits of multi-staged builds in Dockerfiles, but none of the coordination hassles, cause someone else sorted that out already.
